# React not rendering iterated element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to understand why is my loop is not rendered after iterated

```
const ipRangeForm =
  <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
    {
      ipData.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <li style={{marginBottom: '25px', paddingBottom: '15px'}}>
            <Col span="8">
              <FormItem>
                {getFieldDecorator('start[' + index + ']', {
                  initialValue: value.start,
                  rules: [
                    {required: true, message: 'Start IP cannot be empty'}]
                })(
                  <Input placeholder="Start IP" />
                )}
              </FormItem>
            </Col>
            <Col span="1" style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}> - </Col>
            <Col span="8">
              <FormItem>
                {getFieldDecorator('end[' + index + ']', {
                  initialValue: value.end,
                  rules: [
                    {required: true, message: 'End IP cannot be empty'}]
                })(
                  <Input placeholder="End IP" />
                )}
              </FormItem>
            </Col>
            <Col span="4"> <a onClick={() => this.removeFromList(value)}><Icon type="delete" style={{
              marginLeft: 12,
              paddingTop: 12,
              color: "#FF0000"
            }} /></a></Col>
          </li>
        )
      })
    }
  </ul>
```

i have ipData coming from props, what happens is, on the first time of showing this it does not render the element, but after loading it for the FIRST TIME, it shows the correct element (iterated). I wonder why isnt my view rendered after completing the iteration? or did i do something wrong?

thanks

Comment: may we see how you populate ```ipData```? maybe you meant ```this.props.ipData```?

Comment: this variable is inside render() , inside i have const { ipData } = this.props which is coming from an API call. already console.log and the data is there it just so happen the element is looped after the whole page has finished rendering. so i thought i needed a way for the page to know when its finished looping and refresh the page

Comment: when you push items into ```ipData``` from the parent component, do you create a new array first? two arrays having the same reference does not trigger a re-render.

Comment: so basically it comes from a 3 component setup ( page, modal and form )
data is fetched from page then passed on to modal through props and eventually to form while i did initialize the props ipData to [] new array prior receiving new data to handle ipData being undefined. is that what you mean?

Comment: yea, so that isn't the issue. Just to clarify, your component does not automatically re-render upon updating the props ```ipData``` from parent?

Comment: yes, here's the log https://ibb.co/hkRqMd if you want to see, so after rendering for the first time its doing the loop and finished the loop and not re-render the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174377/discussion-between-kenlz-and-christopher-pk).